# How to overlay an image over another in P3D

Tags: image, processing, processing.js

In processing.js, how would you overlay an image over another one in P3D mode?

Here is my code:

```
/* @pjs preload="duck.jpg"; */
/* @pjs preload="a.png"; */ 
PImage imageDuck;
PImage imageA;

void setup() {
    size(500, 500, P3D);
    imageDuck = loadImage("duck.jpg");
    imageA = loadImage("a.png");
}

void draw() {
    background(255);
    noStroke();
    image(imageDuck, 0, 0);
    image(imageA, 0, 0);
}
```

So what the code trying to do is to display a duck image, then overlay another image name a.png (with transparent background) on top of it.

When I use the normal **size(500, 500);** without the P3D mode, the image overlay works perfectly.

However, I am using P3D because the next thing I am going to do is to rotate my images together.

So in this **size(500, 500, P3D)** mode, I can see my a.png flashed once, then only my duck image shows.  If I comment out duck, a.png will show.  If I comment out a.png, my duck shows.  If I reorder the image() call, still only the duck image shows.  I added translate(0,0,-1) or translate(0,0,1) in between my image() calls, no luck, only my duck image shows.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem, it is the first line @pjs, can only be called once.  Multiple images will have to be preloaded within one single line.  In my example, my first 2 lines will have to be combined like such:

```
/* @pjs preload="duck.jpg,a.png"; */
```